# Run chrome with different ip addresses

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, proxy, ip

I have ubuntu server and run google chrome on it to monitor some sites.
In order to prevent my ip from banning I need change it dynamically.

How can I launch google-chrome every time with different ip addresses?
I suspect I should use some proxy server. But is it possible to keep connection as fast as without proxy and change my ip dynamically?
I'm ready to consider non-free solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
use "Hola" chrome plugin for changing ip
```

Comment: Looks like it's good extension, thanks! But how can I run my chrome automatically using Hola? Is it any way to make Hola work on every browser's tab?

Comment: I don't have screen on my server, so I start my google-chrome with command: `google-chrome --load-extension=....`. In this case I won't be able to enable Hola. Does it has some settings where I can set it to be enabled every time even if I restart my browser or even I open new tab?